# how to get form element value before submit in drupal

Tags: 7, users

I have a form with fields for first name and last name. When users log in, I want to redirect them to another page and get first name and last name values.

This is what I tried.

```php
function doner_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  drupal_get_form('doner_step_3');
  $val = $form_state['values']['about_fname'];

  $edit['redirect'] = "http://test.good.com/moll/ijs/d67/step31?fname=$val";
}
```

Comment: Do you wish to store the first and last name permanently, or just to use it temporarily for the page the user is redirected to?

Answer (score 1):

Once an user has logged in, the GLOBALS $user with the information related to this user is ready to use. It isn't neccesary to add an argument to the URL in your redirection.

If it isn't loaded the information you want, you could store that variable in the $user object.

```
function doner_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  drupal_get_form('doner_step_3');
  $GLOBALS['user']->doner_variables = $form_state['values']['about_fname'];
}
```

Comment: `hook_user_login()` does not have access to any `$form_state` variable. Furthermore, it seems the OP wants to get the values submitted from another form, not the login form.

Comment: There is also no need to use `$GLOBALS['user']` as `$account` contains the user object for the account used to log in.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_user_login()` implementations should not render a new form; they should change the values of the `$account` object (which is for the account used to log in), save values in a database table, or redirect users to a different page, for example.

It is not clear from the question which form is the *doner_step_3* form, which values it contains, and in which way those values are related to the logged-in user.
Supposing that `doner_get_fname($uid)` is a function that returns a user first name given the user ID, the code to use should be similar to the following one.

```php
function doner_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $edit['redirect'] = 'http://test.good.com/moll/ijs/d67/step31?fname=' . doner_get_fname($account->uid);
}
```

`doner_get_fname()` should retrieve the first name from where the form submission handler for the *doner_step_3* form stored it. Normally, the values submitted in a form are stored in persistent variables or a database table. (In the case of values associated to users, the latter is more common.)